# Neo4j Webadmin Overview Dashboard: From where is the created_on information retrieved?

Tags: neo4j

Afaik there is no meta-information per default stored when creating a node, relationship or property. Therefore I use custom created_on, modified_on timestamp properties. I was just wondering, the OVerview dashboard (http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#) depicts date information on the horizontal axis. Where is this information stored?
I am using Neo4j 2.1.5
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is stored in `data/graph.db/rrd`. Please note that these numbers a just a indicator and should not be treated as precise counters. Instead of real counts they use the largest id in use.

If you want to use `created_on` and `modified_on` timestamps you can use e.g. Cypher's `MERGE` in combination with the `timestamp()` function:

```
 MATCH (a:Person {name:...}), (b:Product {name:...})
 MERGE (a)-[r:BUYS]->(b)
 ON CREATE SET r.created=timestamp()
 ON MATCH SET r.updated=timestamp()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. When persisting objects I am using merge and differentiate between identifying properties (one could think of them as kind of composite primary key), and non-identifying properties (like timestamps).

Comment: the identifiying properties are then to be used in the `MERGE` clause, the non identifying are best set in `ON CREATE/ON MATCH` parts.